# Who do I deliver Cawlin's letter to?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Actually, the title is intentionally vague to avoid spoilers for people who haven't played the game.

Cawlin gave me a letter to deliver to Karane.  However, I also have the option of delivering it to the mysterious ghostly hand in the Restroom.

What do I gain from choosing the former over the latter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you gain nothing from doing these "quests" except **5 Gratitude Crystals** and some changes to characters that doesn't seem to affect the story.

I tried both options and here's what happens for both:
<sub>(I forgot the exact details on some parts but I'll outline the decisions I made and what happened as best as I can)</sub>

My first run I gave it to the "voice coming from the bathroom."

> The hand in the bathroom was grateful and claimed that it would not read the letter and would use it for "other purposes."  Well, he/she/it lied and suddenly gets infatuated with **Cawlin**.  I believe you get the **5 Gratitude Crystals** here.

> Telling **Cawlin** about it, he runs back to **Groose's** room hating **Link** for what happened.  If you talk to him during the day, he will mention not being able to sleep.  If you visit him at night, you will find the hand with him... doing stuff (nothing dirty ;).  **Karane** just goes about her business.  Nothing else happens throughout the game AFAIK.

Giving the letter to **Karane**, a number of things happened...

> Before handing the letter to **Karane**, she mentions liking **Pipit** to herself.  Proceeding to hand it to her, she asks if it came from **Pipit**.  I chose to tell the truth and said it was from **Cawlin**.  She reads it and is impressed but wants you to tell **Pipit** about this in the hopes of him having feelings for her.

> Talking to **Pipit**, he contemplates whether he has feelings for her and I believe you have the choice to nudge him either way.  I nudged him toward **Karane** and he decided that he *loves* her.

> Returning back to **Karane**, **Cawlin** is there talking to her.  He's there *confessing his love for her*.  **Pipit** arrives and says that *he's* in love with her.  (*draaaamaaa*)  **Karane** thinks about what's going on and ultimately chooses **Pipit**.  **Cawlin** runs back to **Groose's** room feeling sorry for himself.  **Karane** and **Pipit** are together and you get **5 Gratitude Crystals** from **Karane**.  The hand disappears forever.

---

> It looks like no path goes real well for **Cawlin** at all.  ;)

Comment: I went with the hand, I'll post on any further developments.

Answer (score 0):

I find helping out the hand to be much creepier (also for Cawlin).  If you help Karane & Pipit get together that's totally worth it.  Cawlin will get over it.  Just not over the ghost girl haunting him forever o_O